# Videoview bad quality when use vitamio library on some android device

Tags: android, media-player, android-videoview, vitamio

I am using **Vitamio library** into my project to play stream video.

It's worked fine on majority Android devices.
But on some devices, video quality is very bad (**example**: *Samsung galaxy Y S5360, LG L-07C,...*)

I am used:

```
mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
mVideoView.setVideoQuality(MediaPlayer.VIDEOQUALITY_HIGH);
mVideoView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBX_8888);
```

but it's still not change.

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: Same problem here...

Answer (score 2):

I just found the answer.
Just put this line when initialising the VideoView:

```
    mVideoView.setVideoChroma(MediaPlayer.VIDEOCHROMA_RGB565);
```

Comment: I have tried and video was divided into 2 video with quality very bad on android 4.3 :-(

Answer (score 0):

It looks like different pixel format of video and surface View. 
Set mVideoView.setVideoChroma(MediaPlayer.VIDEOCHROMA_RGB565); and mVideoView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGB_565);